# QBoxLayout spacing

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QBoxLayout to display leaderboards from a database. I want to align them so, but nothing seems to work. I used setAlignment, added blank spaces and removed spacing and margin and there are still spacings in between where i don't want them.

```
   PlayerList * playerList= new PlayerList();
   int xPos=this->width()/2 -200;
   int yPos=100;
   QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/FredokaOne-Regular.ttf");
   QFont f("Fredoka One", 12, QFont::Normal);
   QSqlQuery query;
   query.exec(query);

   QVBoxLayout * layoutV=new QVBoxLayout;
   while(query.next()){
   Label1 = new QLabel;
   Label2 = new QLabel;
   Label3 = new QLabel;
   Label1->setFont(f);
   Label2->setFont(f);
   Label3->setFont(f);
   Label1->setStyleSheet("color: white");
   Label2->setStyleSheet("color: white");
   Label3->setStyleSheet("color: white");
   QHBoxLayout * layoutH= new QHBoxLayout;
   Label1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Minimum);
   Label2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Minimum);
   Label3->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Minimum);
   Label1->setText(query.value(0).toString());
   Label2->setText(query.value(1).toString());
   Label3->setText(query.value(2).toString());

   int val=0;
   QString yea = "";
   int text = 0;
   text = Label3->text().length();
   if(text<=16){
       val=16-text;
       for(int i=0;i<val;i++) yea+=" ";
   }
   Label3->setText(query.value(2).toString()+yea+"      ");
   yea = "";
   text = Label1->text().length();
   if(text<=16){
       val=16-text;
       for(int i=0;i<val;i++) yea+=" ";
   }
   Label1->setText(query.value(0).toString()+yea+"      ");
   yea="      ";
   qDebug() << Label1->text() << yea << Label3->text() << yea << Label2->text();

   layoutH->addStretch();
   layoutH->addWidget(Label1);
   layoutH->addWidget(Label3);
   layoutH->addWidget(Label2);
   layoutH->addStretch();
   layoutH->setSpacing(0);
   layoutV->addLayout(layoutH);
    } 

   playerList->setStyleSheet("background-color: black");
   playerList->setLayout(layoutV);
   scene->addWidget(playerList->scrollArea)->setPos(xPos,yPos);
```

https://imgur.com/2MM9rcE
this is what it looks like in the layout, and this is how it looks like in qDebug:
https://imgur.com/VNduNdz

Comment: Use a `QGridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess for me which is the ideal state you'd like.

That which is definitely missing is the usual:

```
layout->addWidget(label);
```

This way `label`is from now on governed by `layout`.

Only then it is worth thinking about trimming too long strings and so on.